# Get SamAccountName without querying LDAP

Tags: asp.net, ldap, asp.net-identity

I could have sworn that just the other week I figured out how to get the SamAccountName for a user *without* having to query LDAP. I was thinking that I got it by casting `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity` to a `WindowsIdentity`. However, as I'm looking at it now I don't see the SamAccountName anywhere.

We have been having issues with LDAP queries, so to mitigate the issue, I thought I found a way to avoid them altogether (with the exception of a single query to get group SIDs on startup).

So my first question is whether it's possible at all to get the SamAccountName without querying LDAP (in other words, is it already located on the principal or identity objects somewhere)?

If it's not, then my second question is: how reliable would it be to try to determine the value based on the Name property? For example, if the Name property says "MYCOMPANY\myname" then how reliably could I assume the SamAccountName is "myname"?